# jQuery image gallery preview image popup

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, preview

I've created an image gallery with the preview image popup on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/WSfka/

Hover over the thumbnail images and the larger image preview displays.

I'm not happy with the way preview images can flash between moving around the thumbnail images. How can I simplify the script and improve the preview image popup?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imageGalleryAlbum li a img').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').find('.preview').delay(500).fadeIn(1);
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.preview').fadeOut(1);
        return;
    });
    $('.imageGalleryAlbum li .preview').hover(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.preview').fadeOut(1);
        return;
    });
    $('.imageGalleryAlbum li .preview').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').find('.preview').fadeOut(1);
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.preview').fadeOut(1);
        return;
    });
    $('.imageGalleryAlbum li .preview').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('li').find('.preview').fadeOut(1);
        $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('.preview').fadeOut(1);
        return;
    });
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $(".preview");
    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.fadeOut(1);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Typically, the `.hover()` method signature includes a `mouseenter` and a `mouseleave` event like so `hover( handlerIn(eventObject) , handlerOut(eventObject)  )`. You seem to have all the events. My guess is they might be cancelling out each other or mashing up together to create a frankin-event of sorts. Will take a look in another 15 mins odd to see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**THIRD UPDATE**

Try this

[Updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/WSfka/9/)

```
var x;  

$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.imageGalleryAlbum li a img').on('mouseenter', function() {

            $('.preview').stop().hide();

            x = $(this).closest('li').find('.preview');

            if( $(x).is(':visible') ) {
                $(x).show();
            } else {
                $('.preview').hide();
                $(this).closest('li').find('.preview').stop().delay(500).fadeIn(0);
            }
        });


        $('.preview').parent().on('click mouseleave', function() {
            $('.preview').hide();
        });

    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        var container = $(".preview");
        if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            container.fadeOut(1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but I still would like the half second delay, if that's possible?

Comment: That's getting closer. Just needs to make sure the other sibling previews close as well.

Comment: Just added one more tweak in case you want the fade in to be longer than .fadeIn(0)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this example.

http://nemanjamilosavljevic.com/javascript/gallery_view/
This is a gallery that I've made, and it does what you needed, and also it allows a user to move their mouse, and still have the large image opend.

Hope that the approach helps you, or that you can use an entire example.

Cheers ;)